# I want when user visit any video do hide this video from videos list in the next visit

Tags: actionscript-3

I made three tables in database

User table (user_id,user_name,user_pass)

Video Table (video_id,video_name,video_url)

viewing Table (view_id,user_id,video_id)

I want when user visit any video 
do hide this video from videos list in the next visit

Sorry I do not speak English well, I hope you understand me

Comment: You need to set a cookie, and then check it, at the next visit. That can be done by using JQuery [plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

Comment: @Igor he is talking about action script!

Answer (score -1):

As you have no code provided in your question.  I don't too.

You need sharedobject a same thing like cookie for action script 3

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/